Unable to delete Lambda function from AWS API Gateway (Lambda still in use by API Gateway)
For a couple of days I've been dealing with this issue, and haven't figured out what's missing.
What I'm trying to do, is remove a Lambda Function from the API Gateway. I don't want to delete the whole Lambda Function itself (though that's not even possible).
My best guess would be that the Lambda function that I'm trying to remove is still being referenced by a deployment from the past (due to the; 'retainDeployments: true')?
My ApiGatewayStack looks like this:
import { Stack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { StackPropsConfig } from "../config/stackPropsConfig";
import { Deployment, DomainName, EndpointType, LambdaIntegration, RestApi, Stage } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway";
import { IHostedZone } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53";
import { ICertificate } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-certificatemanager";


interface ApiGatewayProps extends StackPropsConfig {
    hostedZone: IHostedZone;
    certificate: ICertificate;
    testLambda: LambdaIntegration;
    createPost: LambdaIntegration;
    getPost: LambdaIntegration;
}

export class ApiGatewayStack extends Stack {
    public readonly customDomain: DomainName;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ApiGatewayProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const apiGateway = new RestApi(this, `butlai-api-gateway-${props.config.ENV}`, {
            deploy: false
        });

        this.customDomain = apiGateway.addDomainName(`butlai-api-gateway-custom-domain-${props.config.ENV}`, {
            domainName: props.config.ENV_URL,
            certificate: props.certificate,
            endpointType: EndpointType.EDGE,
        });

        // Explicitly create a deployment for v1
        const deploymentV1 = new Deployment(this, `butlai-api-deployment-v1-${props.config.ENV}-${Date.now()}`, {
            api: apiGateway,
            retainDeployments: true,
        });

        // Create a stage for v1
        new Stage(this, `butlai-api-stage-v1-${props.config.ENV}`, {
            deployment: deploymentV1,
            stageName: 'v1'
        });

        // Create resources and methods for v1
        const postsResourcesV1 = apiGateway.root.addResource("posts");
        postsResourcesV1.addMethod("POST", props.createPost);

        const postResourcesV1 = postsResourcesV1.addResource("{id}");
        postResourcesV1.addMethod("GET", props.getPost);
        postResourcesV1.addMethod("DELETE", props.testLambda);
    }
}

Now, I would like to delete the latest method:
// postResourcesV1.addMethod("DELETE", props.testLambda);

But this results in the following error in the Console:
The CloudFormation Console for this stack tells me this:
Export ButlaiLambdaStack-dev:ExportsOutputFnGetAtttestFunctionFOOBAR cannot be deleted as it is in use by ButlaiApiGatewayStack-dev
But there aren't any other references to that testLambda function elsewhere in my codebase. Next to that, I'm not trying to DELETE the whole Lambda function, I want to deploy a new version of the API without that Method.
Am I missing something? Or what I have to do to make this work?
Any tip would be helpful!
Cheers
UPDATE 1
Launcher.ts file
import { App } from "aws-cdk-lib"
import { NetworkStack } from "./stacks/NetworkStack";
import { AppConfig } from "./config/types";
import { loadConfig } from "./config/loadConfig";
import { DataStack } from "./stacks/DataStack";
import { LambdaStack } from "./stacks/LambdaStack";
import { ApiGatewayStack } from "./stacks/ApiGatewayStack";
import { CertificateStack } from "./stacks/CertificateStack";
import { Route53Stack } from "./stacks/Route53Stack";
import { ApiGatewayDomain } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53-targets";
import { SecurityStack } from "./stacks/SecurityStack";


const app = new App();

const appConfig: AppConfig = loadConfig(app);

const route53Stack = new Route53Stack(app, `ButlaiRoute53Stack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig,
})

const certificateStack = new CertificateStack(app, `ButlaiCertificateStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig,
    hostedZone: route53Stack.hostedZone
});
certificateStack.addDependency(route53Stack);

const networkStack = new NetworkStack(app, `ButlaiNetworkStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig
});

const securityStack = new SecurityStack(app, `ButlaiSecurityStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    vpc: networkStack.vpc,
});
securityStack.addDependency(networkStack);

const dataStack = new DataStack(app, `ButlaiDataStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig,
    vpc: networkStack.vpc,
    databaseSecurityGroup: securityStack.databaseSecurityGroup,
});
dataStack.addDependency(securityStack);

const lambdaStack = new LambdaStack(app, `ButlaiLambdaStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig,
    vpc: networkStack.vpc,
    databaseSecrets: dataStack.databaseSecrets,
    lambdaSecurityGroup: securityStack.lambdaSecurityGroup,
    databaseSecurityGroup: securityStack.databaseSecurityGroup,
});
lambdaStack.addDependency(dataStack);

const apiGatewayStack = new ApiGatewayStack(app, `ButlaiApiGatewayStack-${appConfig.ENV}`, {
    config: appConfig,
    hostedZone: route53Stack.hostedZone,
    certificate: certificateStack.certificate,
    testLambda: lambdaStack.testLambdaFunction,
    createPost: lambdaStack.createPostLambdaFunction,
    getPost: lambdaStack.getPostLambdaFunction,
});
apiGatewayStack.addDependency(route53Stack);
apiGatewayStack.addDependency(certificateStack);
apiGatewayStack.addDependency(lambdaStack);


If the export is used by another stack then you can't delete it without first re-deploying the dependent stack so that it's not dependent. Other related questions here and here.

I've updated the Question by adding the Launcher.ts file, I'm 100% sure that I'm not using that testLambdaFunction elsewhere than the ApiGatewayStack...

Did you check the ButlaiApiGatewayStack-dev stack for import references?

Thanks for the tip, I never looked at the <STACK>.template.json file before.
I just ran cdk synth and took a look at the corresponding file.
There are no references to the 'DELETE', 'testLambda' or 'deletePost' anymore in that file.
Is there something else I can check?
